# Django reference managers and related managers on a model instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Is there a way to reference a model's ManyToMany, Related, ForeignKey fields through a variable?

For example

```
Class Video (models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='videos')

var v = 'videos'

userObj = User.objects.get(username='bob')

userObj.v.filter(...)
```

I want to do this so I can pass those managers into a method and call them on some instance later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use `getattr` to get an attribute via a string.](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr)

```
v = 'videos'
getattr(userObj, v).filter(...)
```